# Rails: Time validation without invalid dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I have a field in the database:

```
t.datetime "start_time"
```

And an API which allows a user to send in a date as a string in the format:

> YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZ

My issue is when an invalid date is passed through (but in the correct format (e.g. January 50th, 2015)), the `ArgumentError: invalid date` exception is thrown before validation begins, thus just returning a 500 error.

I was thinking about overriding the `start_time=` and `start_time` methods in the model and rescuing that exception, but it seems kind of sloppy and validation wouldn't be as straight forward.

I want an invalid date to return an invalid date validation error message, but also work nicely with my presence validation check as on `start_time` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a virtual attribute to store the string and then handle the conversion in a custom validator. This way you can handle the `ArgumentError` in the validation and return an error from the validation process? e.g.

```
 class SomeClass < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :start_time_temp

   validate :valid_start_time
   validates :start_time, presence: true
   def valid_start_time
     begin 
       self.start_time = start_time_temp
     rescue ArgumentError
       errors.add(:start_time, "is not valid.")
     end
   end
end
```